# Why protobuf CopyFrom() & MergeFrom() work for every message type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers, cross-platform, static-linking

Seeing a weird issue in my protobuf setup with all the compilers (g++/Linux, clang/Mac, msvc/Windows). Here is its minimal form:

```
message A {  // declare objA
  int32 i;
}
message B {  // declare objB
  string s;
  repeated bytes rb;
}

...
objA.CopyFrom(objB);  // No compiler error?!
```

I was expecting a compiler error for `CopyFrom()` (or `MergeFrom()`) such as *"no matching function call ..."*. But it works fine in all environments! The declaration of the method in .pb.h looks fine. It just expects type `A` only. It gives compiler error for other non-protobuf types though.

Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: what is `objB` ? What error did you expect?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, have updated the post. `A objA` and `B objB` should not be copyable to each other by `CopyFrom()` method. This method has specific argument of `const A&` or `const B&` type. It's mystery, how it works!

Answer (score 5):

> Why protobuf CopyFrom() & MergeFrom() work for every message type?

Because there's an overloaded version of `CopyFrom` and `MergeFrom`:

```
void CopyFrom(const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message& from) final;
void MergeFrom(const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message& from) final;
```

Since `B` is derived from `Message`, there's no compiler error.

However, if you try to copy or merge two different types, a runtime check will fail, and throw an exception.

```
[libprotobuf FATAL protobuf/src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc:74] CHECK failed: (to->GetDescriptor()) == (descriptor): Tried to merge messages of different types (merge B to A)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: (to->GetDescriptor()) == (descriptor): Tried to merge messages of different types (merge B to A)
Abort trap: 6
```

> Why these overloads exist?

Because you can use protobuf reflection to dynamically create a `Message` whose real type is `A` (the reflection interfaces return the base class, i.e. `Message`, instead of the real type). In this case, you can use these overloads to copy or merge from a dynamically generated `Message`.

Comment: I suspected so. But then the class method should overload it, isn't it?? Where this method declared BTW.

Comment: These methods are virtual methods of the base class, i.e. `Message`. However, each user defined protobuf messages overrides them.

Comment: If they are overridden / overloaded then it should have given compiler error isn't it? Or there has to be a "using Base::CopyFrom" declaration somewhere. Somehow I am not able to see them.