# In protobuf, is copyFrom preferred to assignment?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

The following code will fail at runtime :

```
auto cell = addFilterCell(m_filterSlot, idx, odx, section_idx, 48000);
if(request->has_iir()) {
    auto filter = cell->mutable_iir();
    filter->CopyFrom(request->iir());
} else if(request->has_fir()) {
    auto filter = cell->mutable_fir();
    filter->CopyFrom(request->iir()); // Runtime failure
```

Because I try to copy a IIR message into a FIR messages.
But if I used assignment, the wrong code would fail at compile time :

```
if(request->has_iir()) {
    auto filter = cell->mutable_iir();
    *filter = request->iir();
} else if(request->has_fir()) {
    auto filter = cell->mutable_fir();
    *filter = request->iir();  //compile time error
```

However, I see a lot of copyFrom usage, and it is encouraged [here](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/0HbzhDpAmiU?pli=1).
From my point of view, in the above case, using assignment is safer.
What are the possible downsides of using assignment ?

Internally, the assignment operator is a wrapper around copyFrom, according to this piece of generated code.

```
class FilterCell : public ::google::protobuf::Message /* @@protoc_insertion_point(class_definition:dio.endpoint.FilterCell) */ {
 public:
  FilterCell();
  virtual ~FilterCell();

  FilterCell(const FilterCell& from);

  inline FilterCell& operator=(const FilterCell& from) {
    CopyFrom(from);
    return *this;
  }
```

Comment: @JishanShaikh I think you could make this comment an answer.

Comment: Not related, but I would like to see the source of this generated code.

Comment: `Operator=(const A &)` is the same as `CopyFrom(const A &)`. However, `CopyFrom` has two overloads. That's why, in your first case, it compiles but fail at runtime. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119418/why-protobuf-copyfrom-mergefrom-work-for-every-message-type/73131911#73131911) for detail.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is in [the link you provided](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/0HbzhDpAmiU?pli=1).

> *"The **assignment operator simply wraps CopyFrom**, so the behavior is **exactly the same**. Stylistically we prefer to use CopyFrom over =, because it can be an expensive operation and = makes it look deceptively simple. The operator= overload primarily exists for compatibility with STL, but of course you're free to use it as you choose."*

<sup>*emphasis mine*</sup>

It says that the assignment operator is overloaded and simply wraps the `copyFrom()` function. So there is no behavioural difference between the two.

Comment: OK, I edited my question while you were answering.

Comment: @shodanex Oh I see, but still, the answer remains the same. The only difference is an extra level of indirection. It may be better to use the assignment operator since it's the standard way to do a copy, for example if you use it in whatever library function that needs to do a copy and obviously would not know anything about `copyFrom`. For me, the only reason to use `copyFrom()` would be a semantic preference, but in practice, using the assignment operator should be preferred (imho).

Comment: @Fareanor The assignment operator is not overloaded and wrapped for all the classes that use CopyFrom, e.g., the [message.cc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/a9625006c4a4cc6b38dd20ce5f90d6ac1472cb64/src/google/protobuf/message.cc#L99) does not overload = directly. I can see a couple of classes there that overload the assignment operator to use CopyFrom, and this should be the default implementation.

Comment: Maybe related or not, that quote is from 11 years ago, and I am not able to find the relevant details following this.

Answer (score 0):

The differences between them is that the `copyFrom` does deep copy, whereas the assignment = does shallow copy. `copyFrom` is usually recommended because most of the time we need to ensure that all the values are copied, and for large objects/variables shallow copy is not feasible/recommended anyway.

Apart from that, built-in functions manipulating message objects have error checking and validation (most of the time by design), which can help prevent issues such as data corruption or security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that shallow copy thing ? The protobuf documentation mentions an assignment operator is generated for a message.

Comment: I don't know that lib, but I would be surprised if they did not provide a proper `operator=()` overload. It doesn't make sense to me to create a "copyFrom()" function.

Comment: @shodanex Assignment operator is a directive of C++ and can vary to the compiler implementations. In popular compilers GCC, clang, MVCC, the default behavior of assignment operator is shallow copy. For the functionality of deep copy, we have to overload the assignment operator for our class. A reference: [Myers notes](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/notes/automatics.html#:~:text=Like%20the%20copy%20constructor%2C%20the,version%20makes%20a%20shallow%20copy.).

Comment: @JishanShaikh But the assignment operator can be overloaded ! And should be, for classes that handle some resources for example.

Comment: And it is in the context of protobuf

Comment: *assignment = does shallow copy* this is wrong with protobuf.

Comment: The behaviour of assignment in c++ is well defined and should not vary between compiler implementations