# Copying content of a dynamic message into a generated one

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

For reasons beyond my control I have to deal with generated and dynamic messages in the same codebase. I'm looking for an efficient way to copy content of a dynamic message into a specific generated one.

```cpp
Message* msg;  // Dynamic I get from upstream
MyMessage mymsg; // Generated to be passed downstream
```

I know I can serialize `msg` and deserialize it back into `mymsg`

```cpp
mymsg.ParseFromString(msg->SerializeAsString());
```

This works fine, but doesn't seem to be very efficient.

I tried using `CopyFrom`

```cpp
mymsg.CopyFrom(*msg);
```

but it fails with

```
Error: CHECK failed: (from.GetDescriptor()) == (descriptor): : Tried to copy from a message with a different type. to: foo.MyMessage, from: foo.MyMessage
```

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119418/why-protobuf-copyfrom-mergefrom-work-for-every-message-type) hints, that some similar should be possible, but the solution eludes me.

Comment: "This works fine, but doesn't seem to be very efficient" - Is it a source of an actual performance problem? Did your profiler show this as a performance hotspot (when running an optimized build of the code)? If not, why do you really care? Micro-optimizing things that take a few handfuls of nanoseconds to take a few nanoseconds less, in code that's only called a few times (or a few times per second) in an application is not really worth the effort (IMHO).

Comment: "I have to deal with generated and dynamic messages" - Could you explain what those terms mean in the context of your application? It's not clear from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If the serialised version of each is identical, such that you convert one to the other via the wire format (as in your question), you possibly do not need the dynamic version at all. If your contact with "upstream" is "we're going to send you messages that look like this", then you don't need their code to parse them.

Admittedly, if you had to link to / interop with existing C++ code that was already written wround the dynamic version, you could be stuck with that.

If you are stuck with existing code, perhaps reflection is the answer. I don't know what could be done with C++ and the "reflection" Google build in. In the C# versions, one can iterate over / navigate the structure of a message finding fields, and copying them to like-named-like-positioned fields in another class. That's a simple algorithm that avoids writing a load of dull `g.field1 = d.field;` style code, but avoids the serialise / deserialise conversion. Whether or not the same thing can be done in C++ with what Google include, I don't know. However, the performance is not likely to be much better (if at all) than serialising / deserialising.